# Why two generic types cannot be compared with '=='?

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my simple code:

```
T a;
T b;

if (a == b)
// sth.
else
// sth. else
```

When I try to compile, I get an error saying the `==` operator is invalid for generic types. So I have to use the `object.Equals()` method.

Doesn't the `==` operator actually call the `Equals` method of `object`? Why can I use the `Equals` method of two generic types but not the `==` operator?

Comment: I just checked, and the code sample seems to compile (after adding boilerplate and braces).  Can you show a fuller code sample?

Comment: David, you've asked 10 questions and accepted 0 answers. Do you know how to mark the correct answer as accepted?

Comment: Nevermind ...  It seems the compiler was optimizing away the unnecessary `a == b` comparison, because they were both set to `null` (or something; not entirely sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator ==` must be overloaded in structs in order to be used, hence a completely unconstrained type parameters cannot use it. You can constrain the function to `class` to allow default reference comparison:

```
    public void Foo<T>() where T : class {
        T a = default(T);
        T b = a;

        if(a == b)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        else
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
```

The above code works because by default, reference types can be used with [`operator ==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(v=VS.80).aspx):

> For reference types other than string,
>   == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object.

This is why `if (new object() == new object()) {}` compiles, even though `System.Object` doesn't overload `operator ==`.

Answer (score 2):

The == operator is not defined all possible values of T [thanks Daniel] (or on any constraints you may have placed on T, I assume), so you can't use it.  You can only call operators, methods, properties on T that can be called on ALL possible types represented by T.

operator == calls 'Equals' in many cases, but that doesn't mean they are the same thing.

Comment: Actually, operator == *is* defined on object, just not on structs. And for most reference types, == does *not* call .Equals. The former usually implements identity comparison (except for immutable types) and the latter usually implements value comparison.

Comment: A quick survey with ndepend shows that most reference types in the BCL don't define operator== - giving them ReferenceEquals not value comparison behavior. 

It's interesting to note that operator== isn't actually defined on `object` as far as I can see - instead I believe the c# (or other language) compilers end up compiling to `.ceq` which for reference types means a reference-equality style check.

Comment: I don't `==` is defined on `object`.  Rather, when no overload for `==` exists, the compiler itself tries interpreting it a reference comparison operator for the particular types given and sees if that makes sense.  Operator overloading doesn't care whether passed-in operands are sealed or unsealed, but the C# reference-equality-check operator does (a reference of an unsealed class type can be compared to one of an interface it does not implement, but a reference to a sealed class cannot).

Answer (score 1):

The `==` token is used to represent two different operators in C#.  The first of them is applicable only if the types of the operands fit a particular defined overload of the "equality-check" operator.  The second test reference equality and is applicable only if one operand is `null`, one operand is a class type and the other an interface that instances of that type could implement, both are interfaces, both are the same class types, or both are class types and one is a supertype of the other.  The first form will not be usable on a generic unless the generic is constrained to a type for which an equality-check overload is defined; the second form is limited to reference types which are known to satisfy a particular one of the indicated conditions.  Note that in some cases, the second operator may be used where the first would be intended, e.g. `bool IsSame<T>(T p1, T p2) where T:class { return p1==p2; }` will compare two variables of type `String` by using a reference comparison, even though an overload of `==` is defined for `String`.  This occurs because `T` isn't well-enough known to apply a `String` overload of `==`, but both operands of `==` are known to be the same reference type.

It may be worth noting that some other languages use different tokens for the two operations C# performs using `==`.  VB.NET, for example, uses `=` for equality comparison and `Is` for reference equality.